# How do you say 'so' in Japanese?

Tags: words

As in 'That cake was so good'. I know I could use とても or something similar but I feel like 'so' expresses a kind of excessiveness that とても doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「とても」 would actually be a valid translation in that context.

Others include:

・「たいへん」

・「実{じつ}に」

・「非常{ひじょう}に」

Informally, you could also use:

・「すごく」

***Very*** informally, you could use:

・「マジ（で）」

・「超{ちょう}」

・「めっちゃ」

Comment: Wow I had no idea you could use たいへん for that, I always used for saying something was “hard”/troublesome